# Countif/Sumif should show empty value instead of 0 in arrayformula

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a lot of arrayformulas wrapped around countif and sumifs functions. I want the countifs/sumifs to return an empty value ("") instead of 0.

My workaround is very expensive and long:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(SUMIFS(Sheet!$C$1:$C; 'Sheet!$A$1:$A; ">="&$A3; Sheet!$A$1:$A; "<="&$B3)=0; ""; SUMIFS(Sheet!$C$1:$C; Sheet!$A$1:$A; ">="&$A3; Sheet!$A$1:$A; "<="&$B3)))
```

Here is an example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xyS0Y4gnG3zLyOGtycWytvTlA1NmqjEAy8H7QJatdSg/edit?usp=sharing

Is there a different way for this?

Comment: I have added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(SUM(QUERY(Sheet2!A:C; 
 "select C 
  where month(A)+1="&MONTH(A3)&" 
    and year(A)="&YEAR(A3); 0)))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=IFERROR(SUM(FILTER(Sheet2!C:C; 
 YEAR(Sheet2!A:A)=YEAR(A3); MONTH(Sheet2!A:A)=MONTH(A3))))
```

[image: 0]